# Is there a way to weave jUnit tests with AspectJ being in two different projects?

Tags: eclipse, junit, aspectj, ajdt

I´m trying to intercept webdriver methods inside JUnit tests that are in one java project. I've created another project with Aspects but could not integrate them both to work together. 
Basically I need to print messages on the console as the test goes through.

Could anyone point me to any direction that does not use Spring? (Searching web gives tons of tutorials with Spring). 
I'm using Eclipse Juno with AJDT installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get one project weaving into another, you need to place the aspects on the aspect path of the test project. To do this:

1. Convert your test project to an AJ project
2. Project -> Properties -> AspectJ Build -> Aspect Path
3. Add the aspect project
4. Full build

This should work.  Alternatively, if you can't convert the test project to an AJ project, add the test project to the In path of your aspect project.  Then launch the tests from the class files of your aspect project.

More on inpath and aspect path here: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that worked! I'm now having other problems, I got stackOverflow exception but I'll try to figure that out. If not, that will be issue to another question. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'd say most likely, you are advising inside one of your own advices.  You may have to add a clause to your pointcut like this: && !cflow(adviceexecution()). See http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html#quick-pointcuts.

Comment: Great Andrew! Thanks very much! Just put the negation !cflow and worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg How do I go about this part: "Then launch the tests from the class files of your aspect project." My aspectProject creates the .class files in its bin folder. Is there a way through eclipse to run it? Or just through CLI? Sorry about grave digging. Just didn't think my question needed a full question. Thanks.

Comment: Is the test project an AJ project? Did you add the original project to the test project's aspect path? If so, you should see the class files of the original project showing up in the test project.